# What is the difference between MinusEqual (-=) and PlusEqual (+=) as used in event declaration c#

Tags: c#

Please I want to know the difference between these two. I often use this `+=` for events like

```
this.btnExport.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnExport_Click);
```

From time to time, I do come across sometimes I do come across some declarations like below.

```
this.cmbClient.SelectedIndexChanged -= new System.EventHandler(this.cmbClient_SelectedIndexChanged);
```

I try checking for what the differences are on msdn yet couldn't find a source. Please any help or clarification would be appreciated.

Comment: One add the other deduct.

Comment: `-=` is the opposite of `+=`

Comment: Yah i understand . But what does -= do in the case of the event above ?

Comment: Here is the documentation that you have missed: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366768.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply put, `+=` subscribe a handler to the event, and `-=` unsubscribes a handler from the event. (If the specified handler isn't an existing subscriber, the attempt is ignored.)

Note that you can use significantly simpler syntax as of C# 2:

```
this.btnExport.Click += this.btnExport_Click;
```

This uses a *method group conversion* to convert `this.btnExport_Click` into an `EventHandler`.

How the event implements subscription and unsubscription is up to the implementation. *Often* it's just a matter of using [`Delegate.Combine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Delegate.Combine) and [`Delegate.Remove`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.remove), but it doesn't have to be. Fundamentally, an event is a bit like a property - except instead of `get` and `set` functionality, it has `add` and `remove`; using `+=` on an event calls the `add` part, and using `-=` calls the `remove` part.

See my [article on delegates and events](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter2/Events.aspx) for more details.

Comment: OMG now i understand. never thought of it that way. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2):

The += will register the event hander to the event.

The -= will unregister the event handler from the event.

Comment: Thank you . Now i understand . Never though of it that way. I never knew we can unsubscribe Handler at runtime.